# peerjs with STUN for webrtc

Tags: webrtc, peerjs

I have developed a webrtc based video chat using peerjs. The solution is working fine but some users are facing problem to establish the call. I guess it is due to NAT and firewall issues.

I have user peerjs as :

```
var peer = new Peer({host: myserver.com], port: 9000, debug: true});
```

I have changed the code to `[passed google stun]` as seen here : https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/peerjs/JzIr7INoTbQ/IIykVNHiv_sJ

Still the same issue. Some user can not connect to peer id.
Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 2):

You need to additionally add a TURN server along with the STUN server addr details you have mentioned. 
For additional TURN or STUN server info, you can refer https://gist.github.com/yetithefoot/7592580